# SVG Animation: Create array of all polygons, apply IDs, and animate them individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to create a pattern generator, and am playing around with a quilt-like SVG file, with about 400 little polygons in it. I want to fill an array with all those polygons, iterate through giving them each a unique numbered id, and the animate them. I'm aware this might be too big a file and that the animation may be slow...I just want to try!

[Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/ferret/pen/emeXpg](http://codepen.io/ferret/pen/emeXpg)

```
JS below, in which the only real DOM reference is to "polygon" and the SVG id of quilt:
$(document).ready(function(){
  var rC = randomColor({count:140}); //init random color generator
  var quilt = Snap.select('#quilt'); //tell snap to look at the SVG called quilt.

  var allPolys = new Array(); //set up empty array
  var foundPolys = document.getElementsByTagName("polygon"); //get all the polygons in the DOM
  allPolys.push(foundPolys); //push them into the empty array
  console.log(allPolys); //make sure it went in (HTMLCollection w/ #)
  var numPolys = allPolys.length; //get the array length
//allPolys is now an array of all the polygons woop woop!


function snow() {
  for (i = 0; i <= numPolys; i++) { //iterate thru dem polys
    return allPolys[i].id = 'tri-' + i; //give them unique ideas (tri-1, tri-2 etc)
    var flakeId = flakes[i].id; //set their id as a variable
    console.log(flakeId);
    var flake = flakes.select(flakeId); // Select each individual flake from our list
    var cx = flake.getBBox().cx; // Get its initial coordinates
    var cy = flake.getBBox().cy;
    animateFlake(flake, cx, cy); // Send it to be infinitely animated
 } //eachPoly
 }//snow

function animateFlake(flake, cx, cy){
  var  $scroller = ($(window).scrollTop()/2).toFixed(1),
  timing = $scroller * 140;// Random transition time between times we specify
  var flakeint = flake.attr({ transform:'0 0'}); // Reset the flake's position to behind the cloud
  var deg = getRandomArbitrary(-360,360); // Random rotation (allows it to go either direction)
  // Animate the flake and do a new animation for it when it's done (repeat this function)
  flake.stop().animate({transform: 't0 200 r'+deg+' '+cx+' '+cy}, timing, function(){ animateFlake(flake, cx, cy);});
  if ($scroller <=0) {
  flake.stop();
 }
   }
$(window).scroll(function(){
 var $percentageComplete = (($(window).scrollTop()/($("html").height()- $(window).height()))*100),
 $scroller = $(window).scrollTop()*0.7,
 $scrollsex = $scroller / 100,
 $tileTop = $(".tiles").offset().top + 50,
 $wH = $(window).height(),
  if ($scroller <= $tileTop) { //if the amount you've scrolled is less than ~ the div height then keep animating this left.
   $(".tileGo").css("-webkit-transform","rotate(" + $scroller + "deg)").animate({"left":$scroller}, $scrollsex);

 snow();
 }
 // Lets us get random numbers from within a range we specify. From MDN docs.
  function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
   return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  }

});
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere ?

Comment: Sorry, ah, yes! I actually figured out a work around which is just to group every polygon in Illustrator and then ungroup them all into separate layers, which gives them all unique layer IDs. 

The question at the time was: how do apply individual IDs to each SVG component using javascript?